# country_select gem throws "NoMethodError", undefined method `country_select' for #

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, form-with

I am new to rails but I think I'm following every step for using this gem.
However, I'm getting a NoMethodError.
My steps:
I ran `gem install country_select -v 3.1.1` in terminal.
I stopped my server, ran bundle install, restarted my server.
I added the method to my code. I tried adding it to my gem file but that caused a different error preventing my Rails Server from running (see below for details). It seems like installing via the terminal should be enough, according to the [github doc.](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select)

The only other stackoverflow issue that seemed to have the same problem as me says it was fixed by restarting the server, but I've tried this several times and it hasn't worked. If anyone can help me here, I'd appreciate it very much!

**note: Since my original question has been answered and the problem evolved, I posted a new question with my terminal issue here: [country_select gem causes "Could not find i18n_data-0.10.0 in any of the sources" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63962800/country-select-gem-causes-could-not-find-i18n-data-0-10-0-in-any-of-the-sources)**

_form.html.erb

```
 <%= form_with(model: [ @contact, @contact.addresses.build ] ) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :street %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :street %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :town %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :town %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :zip %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :zip %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :state %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :state %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :country %><br>
    <%= form.country_select :country %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Contact:</strong>
  <p>
  <%= @contact.salutation %>
  <%= @contact.first_name %>
  <%= @contact.middle_name %>
  <%= @contact.last_name %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <strong>SSN:</strong>
  <%= @contact.ssn %><br>
  <strong>Date of Birth:</strong>
  <%= @contact.dob %><br>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= @contact.comment %>
  </p>
</p>

<h2>Addresses</h2>
<%= render @contact.addresses %>

<h2>Add an address:</h2>
<%= render 'addresses/form' %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contact_path(@contact) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', contacts_path %>
```

Here is the full error from terminal:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 307ms (ActiveRecord: 67.6ms | Allocations: 85354)


  
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `country_select' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x00007fd0dcc18428>):
    17:   </p>
    18:   <p>
    19:     <%= form.label :country %><br>
    20:     <%= form.country_select :country %>
    21:   </p>
    22:   <p>
    23:     <%= form.submit %>
  
app/views/addresses/_form.html.erb:20
app/views/addresses/_form.html.erb:1
app/views/contacts/show.html.erb:23
```

When I add the gem to my gemfile and run bundle install, I cannot restart the server because I get this error:

```
Could not find i18n_data-0.10.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

bundle install returns the following:

```
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Using rake 13.0.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.7
Using i18n 1.8.5
Using minitest 5.14.2
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.7
Using zeitwerk 2.4.0
Using activesupport 6.0.3.3
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubi 1.9.0
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Using nokogiri 1.10.10
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.7.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Using actionview 6.0.3.3
Using rack 2.2.3
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using actionpack 6.0.3.3
Using nio4r 2.5.3
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Using websocket-driver 0.7.3
Using actioncable 6.0.3.3
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activejob 6.0.3.3
Using activemodel 6.0.3.3
Using activerecord 6.0.3.3
Using mimemagic 0.3.5
Using marcel 0.3.3
Using activestorage 6.0.3.3
Using mini_mime 1.0.2
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailbox 6.0.3.3
Using actionmailer 6.0.3.3
Using actiontext 6.0.3.3
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using msgpack 1.3.3
Using bootsnap 1.4.8
Using bundler 2.1.4
Using byebug 11.1.3
Using regexp_parser 1.7.1
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using capybara 3.33.0
Using childprocess 3.0.0
Using i18n_data 0.10.0
Using sixarm_ruby_unaccent 1.2.0
Using unicode_utils 1.4.0
Using countries 3.0.1
Using sort_alphabetical 1.1.0
Using country_select 4.0.0
Using ffi 1.13.1
Using jbuilder 2.10.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.4
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using listen 3.2.1
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using pg 1.2.3
Using puma 4.3.6
Using rack-proxy 0.6.5
Using thor 1.0.1
Using railties 6.0.3.3
Using sprockets 4.0.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.2
Using rails 6.0.3.3
Using rubyzip 2.3.0
Using sassc 2.4.0
Using tilt 2.0.10
Using sassc-rails 2.1.2
Using sass-rails 6.0.0
Using selenium-webdriver 3.142.7
Using spring 2.1.1
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.1
Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Using turbolinks 5.2.1
Using web-console 4.0.4
Using webdrivers 4.4.1
Using webpacker 4.3.0
Bundle complete! 18 Gemfile dependencies, 80 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Comment: Could you post the full error message in a code block?

Comment: I updated, thanks for looking @JakeWorth

Comment: The latest error suggests `Run bundle install to install missing gems.` What happens when you run `bundle install`?

Comment: nothing changes, I'm afraid

Comment: What is the output of the `bundle install` command?

Comment: I've added it above @JakeWorth

Comment: Is that output from the same terminal session where you're trying run the rails server?

Comment: @JakeWorth it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gem install` installs a gem on your computer. If you want to include a gem in your rails app, you need to add it to the gemfile:

```
gem 'country_select', '~> 4.0'
```

I agree, most docs are a bit ambigious in that sense, but they are general because they cannot forsee what the user intends to do with the gem.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I have tried this but when I do so I get a different error, so I think I need to find out why I'm getting this error and resolve that:

Could not find i18n_data-0.10.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: Might be the version you try to install, is there a reason why you don't go with the most recent version but `3.1.1` instead?

Comment: Ah, it was just the version from the page's copy and paste section, but even after updating to 4.0 in both my terminal install and my gemfile, I get the same error.

Comment: I'm going to post a new question regarding that terminal issue since the question has changed a bit now. Thanks for the help, @Clara